# Missing last image in video

Tags: video

With JCodec code below, I'm expecting video showing 4 images for 3 sec., total 12 sec.

However, the video just display 1st, 2nd, 3rd image for 3 sec., then stopped at 9 sec., but the video have total duration of 12 sec.

Can anyone help me?

```
    SeekableByteChannel ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

    MP4Muxer muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

    FramesMP4MuxerTrack outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 1);

    outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(NIOUtils.fetchFrom(image1), 0, 1, 3, 0, true, null, 0, 0));
    outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(NIOUtils.fetchFrom(image2), 3, 1, 3, 1, true, null, 3, 0));
    outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(NIOUtils.fetchFrom(image3), 6, 1, 3, 2, true, null, 6, 0));
    outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(NIOUtils.fetchFrom(image4), 9, 1, 3, 3, true, null, 9, 0));

    outTrack.addSampleEntry(MP4Muxer.videoSampleEntry("png ", new Size(800, 600), "JCodec"));

    muxer.writeHeader();

    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
```

Comment: I have the same problem here, did you find out what was the problem?